# How does Stack Overflow link accounts?

Tags: support, login, merge-accounts

My primary way of signing in is with a Google account. Once I tried to sign in with a GitHub account and it was linked to my previously-created Google account.

How does Stack Overflow make that determination?

Can it be, that I used Google email on GitHub and that provided SO with information to link accounts to one SO profile?

Comment: Presumably you had already added your GitHub account in your [My Logins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/mylogins/current) page.

Comment: Is this page present for many years? If not, then doubtful.

Comment: Yes, it's been there for as long as I can remember. GitHub, specifically, was added as a login method back in [2019](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/11/announcing-support-for-github-authentication-in-stack-overflow/).